# positioning text & bar under a image

Tags: html, css

Top of my html page is horizontally scrollable input images. I have used the **property     white-space:nowrap**;
I am trying to place a text under my every image. But facing some problem :---

1>  All the text is comming under the first image & are overwritten their. (even if i use the property **position: absolute;**)
2>  I am not able to scroll to the images on right. Even scroll bar is not visible on the GUI after adding the text under images .

Actually what i am trying to achieve is :---
Each image will have a text below it and below text their will be an Horizontal bar.
And i should be able to scroll to the images on the right of my screen. Whenever button is pressed i will glow bar under the image indicating button image is selected. Here bar means a horizontal line (with some width) which for which i can change color to indicate image input is selected.

```
===============================
IMAGE | IMAGE | IMAGE | IMAGE | 
TEXT  | TEXT  | TEXT  | TEXT  |
BAR   | BAR   | BAR   | BAR   |
===============================
```

At present code which i have posted does not contains logic for adding BAR under the text.
Please suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<head>
<style>
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

#imgtxt{ 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 40px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
   font-family:arial; 
   color:#DDDFED; 
   font-size:15px;
}

#images {
    background-color:#292B3B;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#Menu {
    background-color:#FFCCFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
}
#center {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:200px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:20px;
}
#fotter {
    background-color:#CC99FF;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}

</style>
</head>

<body >


<div id="images" class="scrollable">
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
 <p id="imgtxt">Keypad</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-2</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-3</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-4</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-5</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-6</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-7</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-8</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-9</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-10</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-11</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-12</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-13</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-14</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-15</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-16</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-17</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-18</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-19</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-20</p>
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
<p id="imgtxt" >Keypad-21</p>
</div>
<div id="Menu"> <b>Main Menu</b>

    <br />BUTTON-1
    <br />BUTTON-2
    <br />BUTTON-3</div>
<div id="center">Table center</div>
<div id="fotter">Copyright © 2014 My First Layout</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B7Njx/

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by bar??

Comment: means a horizontal line (with some width) which for which i can change colour to indicate image input is selected.

Comment: You shouldn't reuse ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` on a div containing your input image and text.

See this demo.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/Z9KG5/7/)**

HTML

```
<div class="input">
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images..." onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <p class="imgtxt">Keypad</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
.input input {
    display: block;
}
.imgtxt {
    margin: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#DDDFED;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

When you use `position: absolute` the element will be positioned relative to its closest parent with position specified. In your example all of the `<p>` tags will be positioned the same.

Comment: text is coming under the image but .. padding is missing between the two images .. if you can see in the attached image each button is seprated by padding of 4px ... also if in your fiddle i put 16 images then the images moves to next row .. there is no horizontal slider and property white-space:nowrap; fails see this edited example .. http://jsfiddle.net/Z9KG5/2/  ... this will show more clearly i just shifted Menu-1 .. http://jsfiddle.net/Z9KG5/3/

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you want a more flexible solution I would suggest that you don't using `position: absolute` to layout your page

Comment: yes its working ... but if i do not use absolute addressing then i am not able to place the div id="Menu" & "center" & "fotter" to its correct location ... can you suggest how to achieve it using relative position ?

Comment: It depends on your requirements for the layout. If you're fine with the layout you, go for it. I just meant that a positioned layout can be a bit unflexible. You could look into flexbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes but that might be to complicated for a simple layout.

Comment: I have not used it before.. can you update it on jsfiddle .. if you have used it .. ?